# Selecting checkbox nested in <td>

Tags: html, imacros

I am trying to the following with IMACROS :

'Check' the check box inside of the below `<td>` BASED on the target="940" attribute in the `<span>` tag.

I tried :

TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:CHECKBOX FORM=ID:aspnetForm ATTR=TARGET:940 CONTENT=YES

but for some reason the target= attribute is not recognized

Any suggestions?

Thank you!!

```html
<td class="someClassName">

<input type="checkbox" name="some_name" id="someIDstring" title="my title">

<span class="someClassName" href="../../Path/Path/NA" target="940" title="my title" id="someIDstring">Here is some text
</span>

</td>
```

Comment: The "nested in <td>" shouldn't play a role, I would think... Why don't you use what iMacros records itself..., which is probably based on the `ID` Attr, instead of your `TARGET`...? :idea: // And the `POS=1` might need to be "adjusted", if there are several CB's...

Comment: Thank! You're correct: IMACROS records the ID, but unfortunately the ID is useless and I'd like to use the TARGET attribute as criteria. I will check your idea regarding the adjustment of POS=1. Was wondering if something like this is possible with IMACROS :IF (TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN FORM=ID:aspnetForm ATTR=TARGET:940) THEN TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:CHECKBOX FORM=ID:aspnetForm ATTR=ID:someIDstring CONTENT=YES

Comment: Alright, I only realize "now" that the `TARGET` Attr doesn't even belong to the 'CB' but to the the 'SPAN' Element, ah-ah...! Then, yep, simply use `R-POS` ('Relative Positioning'), that will also take care of the Conditional Logic... (Many Threads about that Func/Technique on the iMacros Forum...)

Comment: Thanks all. The R-POS did the trick. The following lines here work for my problem: `TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN FORM=ID:aspnetForm ATTR=TARGET:myTargetID
TAG POS=R-1 TYPE=INPUT:CHECKBOX FORM=ID:aspnetForm ATTR=ID:* CONTENT=YES`

Comment: Yep, very good, exactly what I meant...! :happy: